# How to compare two dataframes and add new columns using mutate across?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to compare two dataframes with different sizes and add new columns using mutate across.

This is the dataframe I have.

```
df <- data.frame(No = c(1,2,3,4),
                 s_Ca = c(NA, 250, NA, 500),
                 s_P = c(300, NA, NA, NA),
                 s_Fe = c(NA, 10, NA, NA),
                 s_K = c(NA, NA, NA, 300))
```

and I want to compare it to the dataframe below.

```
intake <- data.frame(cutoff = c(210, 210, 3.6, 1050),
                     nut = c("Ca", "P", "Fe", "K"))
```

If the value of `Ca` in `df` is larger than the cutoff of `Ca` in `intake`, then I would add 1 to the new column `s_Ca_cat`, and else 0.

If the value of `P` in `df` is larger than the cutoff of `P` in `intake`, I would add 2 to the new column `s_P_cat`, and so on.

That is, what I want as a result is like

```
df_cat <- data.frame(No = c(1,2,3,4),
                     s_Ca_cat = c(0, 1, 0 , 1),
                     s_P_cat = c(2, 0, 0, 0),
                     s_Fe_cat = c(0, 3, 0, 0),
                     s_K_cat = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

This is what I tried to do at first.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(!contains("No"),
                ~ ifelse(. >= intake_rep, 1, NA),
                .names = "{.col}_cat"))
```

I was trying easier version, which is adding same value 1 to the new columns and I even stuck with this easier version. It kept returning not a single column, but lists with 2 attributes? (Sorry I'm a newbie of R)

The reason I guessed is the statment `~ ifelse` in `mutate(across)`, but I don't know how to fix it.

1. How can I fix the code that I tried?
2. Could you help me how to add different values to each new column?

I would be so grateful if anyone can help!

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-No, .names = "{.col}_cat",
                ~ ifelse(.x > intake$cutoff[paste0("s_", intake$nut) == cur_column()] & !is.na(.x),
                         match(cur_column(), names(pick(-No))), 0)))

#   No s_Ca s_P s_Fe s_K s_Ca_cat s_P_cat s_Fe_cat s_K_cat
# 1  1   NA 300   NA  NA        0       2        0       0
# 2  2  250  NA   10  NA        1       0        3       0
# 3  3   NA  NA   NA  NA        0       0        0       0
# 4  4  500  NA   NA 300        1       0        0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
intake_new <- intake %>% mutate(ind = row_number())
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-No,  ~ {
  tmp <- subset(intake_new, nut == str_remove(cur_column(), ".*_"))
  case_when(.x > tmp$cutoff ~ tmp$ind, TRUE ~ 0)}, .names = "{.col}_cat"), 
   .keep = "unused")
```

-output

```
  No s_Ca_cat s_P_cat s_Fe_cat s_K_cat
1  1        0       2        0       0
2  2        1       0        3       0
3  3        0       0        0       0
4  4        1       0        0       0
```